# No data in Google Webmaster Tools traffic, content keywords etc

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

My site has been live and added to Google Webmaster Tools for over a year now. It doesn't have a pile of incoming links, but there are a few I know of. The site receives an average of 200 visits/month, so not massive, but not nothing either.

The site is in Webmaster Tools, has a sitemap (which is new, admittedly), but I can see nothing in any of the traffic views, nor in the internal links view.

The only 'unusual' thing I can see about the site is that everything except the home page is served over HTTPS.

Is this normal? I have a friend who runs a website with similar traffic volumes etc, and he can see data in all of these views just fine.

Just as additional background:

- The domain has been verified with WMT.
- The site map has been submitted, and I can see google crawled it ok.
- The index stats show 11 pages indexed.
- I have an associated Analytics account.

Comment: What is the domain name please? I would remove the current WMT verification meta/files/DNS and re-verify too with a fresh user (ideally) so that you definitely confirm that what is verified on your website is definitely the same account that you're looking in.

Comment: @Geoff The website is www.get3sixty.com. I did try deleting and re-adding the site (on the same user) and the same issue remained, but that obviously didn't involve re-verifying. I'll try creating a new user tonight... bit of a pain though, since I log in with my google apps account!

Comment: Thanks Paul. A website configuration is forcing all pages to resolve at https. Your SSL works fine but there is no need to serve content as secure unless the pages contain personal / sensitive information. This can be handled a number of ways but most commonly via .htaccess or you can use the canonical link element to tell Google which version of pages to index - it is best to resolve this server side though. You will likely have added your website (http) and verified in WMT yet site serves (and indexes) as https hence why you see no data.

Comment: Can read more on http and https sites in Google Webmaster Tools [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34592).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are serving the site via `http` and `https` then you will need to add **both** to Google Webmaster Tools to see everything about your site.  I would also recommend adding the `www` and no `www` versions.   In the end you should have **four** verified sites listed in your webmaster tools console:

- `http://example.com/`
- `https://example.com/`
- `http://www.example.com/`
- `https://www.example.com/`

Between these four, you should be able to see all your stats.  My guess is that in your particular case, you have only verified `http://example.com/`.  Since only the homepage is available on that site, you don't have enough data to show the statistics.   Most of your stats will be available only under `https://example.com/`.

Comment: Okay, cool - is there someway to 'merge' the stats, or do I need to look across all four?

Comment: `www` stats usually roll up into the non-`www` versions, but I think you will have to look across the the `http` and `https` versions separately.

Comment: You should refer to my comments above on serving content at the correct URL's rather than leaving as is and looking at merging data. Secure and unsecure protocols exist for a reason :)

Comment: This solution worked, with the caveat that it's not merged. @GeoffJackson, the reason it serves everything except the homepage as https is to prevent cookie hijacking, and allow users to see when they're logged in. When I originally launched, the sharing widgets couldn't cope with SSL, so I had to leave the homepage using HTTP. I could I guess make the homepage SSL now also - would that be any worse (performance hit not withstanding!) as long as I 301 redirect everything?

Comment: @Paul Russell That's fine as long as there is reasoning behind it. Google only has the https pages of your website indexed anyway so sure, serve the homepage as secure also, verify the secure site in WMT as you have done and handle the http to https 301 redirects across the site. No performance hit expected. Glad you got it sorted.